# Combine into function and iterate

Tags: r, loops

I am attempting to combine a series of loops/functions into one all-encompassing function to then be able to see the result for different input values. While the steps work properly when standalone (and when given just one input), I am having trouble getting the overall function to work. The answer I am getting back is a vector of 1s, which is incorrect.

The goal is to count the number of occurrences of consecutive zeroes in the randomly generated results, and then to see how the probability of consecutive zeroes occurring changes as I change the initial percentage input provided.

Does anyone have a tip for what I'm doing wrong? I have stared at this at several separate points now but cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
### Example
pctgs_seq=seq(0.8,1,.01)
occurs=20
iterations=10

iterate_pctgs=function(x) { 
  probs=rep(0,length(pctgs_seq))

  for (i in 1:length(pctgs_seq)) {
    all_sims=lapply(1:iterations, function (x) ifelse(runif(occurs) <= i, 1, 0)) 

    totals=sapply(all_sims,sum)

    consec_zeroes=function (x) {
      g=0
      for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) 
      { g= g+ifelse(x[i]+x[i+1]==0,1,0) }
      return (g) } 

    consec_zeroes_sim=sapply(all_sims,consec_zeroes)

    no_consec_prob=sum(consec_zeroes_sim==0)/length(consec_zeroes_sim)
    probs[i]=no_consec_prob } 
  return (probs)
}

answer=iterate_pctgs(pctgs_seq)
```

Comment: The `rle`- function would seem to be a logical choice for "counting consecutive" anything. However I do not see a [MCVE] on which we might do any testing. It at the level of guesswork as far as what your inputs might look like.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The primary input is the "pctgs_seq" vector above. for each of those percentages, i hope to find the probability given by the "no_consec_prob" variable within the for loop in the example.

Comment: The `answer` result is a bunch of 1's. Is that the desired result?

Comment: No. For instance, the result should be a vector of different probabilities in the 0-10% range. when i run these commands for just one input (i.e. just one value of i), i get less than 5%.

Comment: Since your code is failing to deliver the desired result you need to put more effort into expressing that result and the method to get there.